# I would like to hard code a 'random post' button in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, random

I would like to go to a random post when the random button is clicked. I would like something like below.

```
<div class="randomize">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/?p=<?php get_post('orderby=rand'); ?>" >
        <img src="http://www.example.com/randomize-button.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is a walkthru for you to reference:

[Random Post Button](http://fivera.net/create-random-post-button-css-function-live-example/)

insert into: functions.php

```
add_action('init','explore_button');
function explore_button() {
       global $wp;
       $wp->add_query_var('random');
       add_rewrite_rule('random/?$', 'index.php?random=1', 'top');
}

add_action('template_redirect','random_template');
function random_template() {
       if (get_query_var('random') == 1) {
               $posts = get_posts('post_type=post&orderby=rand&numberposts=1');
               foreach($posts as $post) {
                       $link = get_permalink($post);
               }
               wp_redirect($link,307);
               exit;
       }
}
```

Add this to your HTML:

```
<div class="explore">  
  <div><a href="http://example.com/index.php?random=1 ">EXPLORE</a></div>
```

Add custom CSS.

Answer (score 3):

You may try this

```
<?php 
    $args = array('orderby' => 'rand', 'type'=>'post', 'posts_per_page'=>1);
    $post = get_posts($args);
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post[0]->ID); ?>" >
    <img src="http://www.example.com/randomize-button.png" />
</a>
```